# Change the font style of an existing pdf document with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

Is it possible to change the font style of an existing pdf document using apache PDFBox?
I want to change the existing font style to a new font style (Arial, Helvetica, etc) without changing the orientation of the pdf.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "font style"? Some aspects thereof may be changed more easily than others...

Comment: Style like italic/oblique, bold etc?

Comment: I mean Helvetica, Arial, etc. @mkl

Comment: Whether that is possible or not depends on how the font is specified in the existing PDF. In particular embedded font subsets can present difficulties here. Furthermore, if you replace a font with a different one with different metrics (in particular different character widths), the result may look quite messy.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily do that with online pdf editors if the pdf isn't very complicated.
Here is an editor I've used myself and it does a pretty good job. 
https://www.sejda.com/pdf-editor